# Warnings while executing a function in a function

Tags: scala

I created one function:

```
def ignore(f: Unit => Unit) = {
    userDisabled = true
    f
    userDisabled = false
}
```

Now I get a warning:

> a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses

When I add the parentheses, and write `f()`, I get:

> Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.         signature: Function1.apply(v1: T1): R   given arguments:   after adaptation: Function1((): Unit)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably wanted to declare `ignore` as

```
def ignore(f: () => Unit) = {
    userDisabled = true
    f()
    userDisabled = false
}
```

With is function with 0 arity that returns `Unit`

Currently you have a 1 arg function that expects parameter of type `Unit`. There is only one value with such type and it is `()`.

When you simply say `f`, you do nothing, you don't call the function, hence the first warning. It is as if you just put:

```
userEnabled = true
42
userEnabled = false
```

When you say `f()` you are not passing an argument to a function that expects one. Scala can put there `Unit` for you, but it is deprecated, hence the second warning. You should call it as `f(())`.

Another option could be call by name parameter

```
def ignore(f: => Unit) = {
    userDisabled = true
    f
    userDisabled = false
}
```

in that case `f` would cause side effects to happen each time you use it in the method body. This is the most common way of doing such thing as from caller perspective you can just say

```
ignore {
  //code
}
```

instead of

```
ignore(() => {
  //code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function without parenthesis, `f`, is an indication that it has no side effects, that the function is "pure".  Since your function call without parens isn't the last statement, it would not be returned, and thus has no overall effect.

When you right this `f()` you're writing that your function takes no arguments.  But it really does!  It takes something of type `Unit`.  Before Scala used to infer this for you but due to several issues you must now, since 2.11, provide it manually as `f(())`

Comment: Because nobody wants to pass a unit into a function, it serves no purpose.
Obviously, the ops problem is in that the function is declared incorrectly, as the other answer explains.

Comment: I see.  Yes, that makes sense